# Navigation Drawer visibility issues in Vuetify

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

Since i have updated the vuetify framework from **0.16.9** to **0.17.4** i am facing a weird issue of Navigation drawer not being shown in full screen desktop mode, but works fine in mobile view mode. Issue started from vuetify version (0.17.3)

i have read [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v0.17.3) that the issue is fixed, But some how its now working for me. Anyone has faced or resolved this issue?

> 2b40331 Fixed a bug where v-navigation-drawer was not properly
>   updating the layout when resizing from mobile to desktop resolutions
>
> efdbd80 Fixed a bug where a destroyed v-navigation-drawer would try to
>   evaluate its element

**Mobile view**
[image]
**Desktop view**
[image]

Comment: Seems like a bug in deprecated version. Did you test it on `vuetify-1.x.x`? Any reason you don't update to latest version?

Comment: even on 1.x.x its the same thing... on 0.16.9  i have everything fine. that's y i didn't update. I wish to get fix for this Navigation drawer to update to the latest one.

Comment: can you reproduce on codepen?

Comment: https://codepen.io/veer3383/pen/erJNLp?editors=1010 works like this if i create a SPA vue application, but my application is developed using DotNet Core 2.0 + Vue and i am using typescript for it.

Comment: @Traxo Issue got finally resolved automatically in version 1.0.18